# Problem importing old Eclipse project into Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

Its about time I moved from Eclipse to Studio.
I import an ond Eclipse project and get this error (warning)...
"Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'."
I then try to build the project and it simpy says "Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:].".
If I attempt to run the project (after specifying its a Android App) it says
" Module not specified" and there is no option to add a module.
Nothing seems to work!
Help please!
Many thanks